# Pytorch Model Summary

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to load a pytorch model using:

```
model = torch.load('/content/gdrive/model.pth.tar', map_location='cpu')
```

I want to check the model summary. When I try:

```
print(model)
```

I get the following output:

```
{'state_dict': {'model.conv1.weight': tensor([[[[ 2.0076e-02,  1.5264e-02, -1.2309e-02,  ..., -4.0222e-02,
           -4.0527e-02, -6.4458e-02],
          [ 6.3291e-03,  3.8393e-03,  1.2400e-02,  ..., -3.3926e-03,
           -2.1063e-02, -3.4743e-02],
          [ 1.9969e-02,  2.0064e-02,  1.4004e-02,  ...,  8.7359e-02,
            5.4801e-02,  4.8791e-02],
          ...,
          [ 2.5362e-02,  1.1433e-02, -7.6776e-02,  ..., -3.4798e-01,
           -2.7198e-01, -1.2066e-01],
          [ 8.0373e-02,  1.3095e-01,  1.4240e-01,  ..., -2.2933e-03,
           -1.0469e-01, -1.0922e-01],
          [-1.1147e-03,  7.4572e-02,  1.2814e-01,  ...,  1.6903e-01,
            1.0619e-01,  2.4744e-02]], 
      'model.layer4.1.bn2.running_var': tensor([0.0271, 0.0155, 0.0199, 0.0198, 0.0132, 0.0148, 0.0182, 0.0170, 0.0134,
.
.
.
```

What does it even mean?

I also tried to use:

```
from torchsummary import summary
summary(model, input_size=(3, 224, 224))
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-ca828d30bd38> in <module>()
      1 from torchsummary import summary
----> 2 summary(model, input_size=(3, 224, 224))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchsummary/torchsummary.py in summary(model, input_size, batch_size, device)
     66 
     67     # register hook
---> 68     model.apply(register_hook)
     69 
     70     # make a forward pass

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Please note that model is a custom model that I am trying to load.
How can I get a model summary in Pytorch?

Comment: What is the class of `model`. Does it inherits from `torch.nn.Module`?

Comment: @E_K I am trying to load a pre-trained model from github. It doesn't inherit from `torch.nn.Module`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loaded the "*.pt" and didn't feed it to a model (which is just a dictionary of the weights depending on what you saved) this is why you get the following output:

```
{'state_dict': {'model.conv1.weight': tensor([[[[ 2.0076e-02,  1.5264e-02, -1.2309e-02,  ..., -4.0222e-02,
           -4.0527e-02, -6.4458e-02],
          [ 6.3291e-03,  3.8393e-03,  1.2400e-02,  ..., -3.3926e-03,
           -2.1063e-02, -3.4743e-02],
          [ 1.9969e-02,  2.0064e-02,  1.4004e-02,  ...,  8.7359e-02,
            5.4801e-02,  4.8791e-02],
          ...,
          [ 2.5362e-02,  1.1433e-02, -7.6776e-02,  ..., -3.4798e-01,
           -2.7198e-01, -1.2066e-01],
          [ 8.0373e-02,  1.3095e-01,  1.4240e-01,  ..., -2.2933e-03,
           -1.0469e-01, -1.0922e-01],
          [-1.1147e-03,  7.4572e-02,  1.2814e-01,  ...,  1.6903e-01,
            1.0619e-01,  2.4744e-02]], 
      'model.layer4.1.bn2.running_var': tensor([0.0271, 0.0155, 0.0199, 0.0198, 0.0132, 0.0148, 0.0182, 0.0170, 0.0134,
.
.
.
```

What you should do is:

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
print(model)
```

You can refer to the [pytorch doc](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html)

Regarding your second attempt, the same issue causing the problem, `summary` expect a model and not a dictionary of the weights.

Comment: I am trying to load a pre-trained model from github. How am I supposed to initialize the model in this case, then?

Comment: @user14 You need the model itself, so either copy the definition of it from the same git and set an instance of it or write it yourself. the weights won't help you if you don't have the model

Comment: I am new to Pytorch. I used to use Keras and in Keras normally I would just load the model instead of defining it too. Could you please clarify that in Pytorch every time I have to load a model, I have to define it too? Or Is it just this model only that needs the definition? Thank you!

Comment: @user14 everytime you wish to load a model you need to initialize an instance of the model. Refer to the doc linked in my answer, they go through the process of saving and loading a model